# pbuilder not building correctly

Tags: ubuntu, debian, packaging, pbuilder

This is my first time packaging a debian package so i might be doing something wrong but I've followed the guidelines and after running "pbuilder create" it goes through the process of checking/downloading dependencies. At the end it should give me a .deb package in it's result package but instead it just stops after checking for dependencies. Here's the end of the process:

```
I: Configuring libc-bin...
I: Configuring libjson0:amd64...
I: Configuring libnih-dbus1:amd64...
I: Configuring libselinux1:amd64...
I: Configuring libpng12-0:amd64...
I: Configuring iproute2...
I: Configuring coreutils...
I: Configuring makedev...
I: Configuring ncurses-bin...
I: Configuring libsemanage1:amd64...
I: Configuring tar...
I: Configuring libcgmanager0:amd64...
I: Configuring libncurses5:amd64...
I: Configuring libplymouth2:amd64...
I: Configuring dpkg...
I: Configuring libncursesw5:amd64...
I: Configuring sysvinit-utils...
I: Configuring dash...
I: Configuring perl-base...
I: Configuring libudev1:amd64...
I: Configuring mountall...
I: Configuring initramfs-tools-bin...
I: Configuring sed...
I: Configuring grep...
I: Configuring gzip...
I: Configuring bash...
I: Configuring debconf...
I: Configuring libpam0g:amd64...
I: Configuring sysv-rc...
I: Configuring tzdata...
I: Configuring kmod...
I: Configuring libpam-modules-bin...
I: Configuring module-init-tools...
I: Configuring libpam-modules:amd64...
I: Configuring passwd...
I: Configuring libpam-runtime...
I: Configuring login...
I: Configuring libuuid1:amd64...
I: Configuring adduser...
I: Configuring libblkid1:amd64...
I: Configuring util-linux...
I: Configuring libmount1:amd64...
I: Configuring mount...
I: Configuring initscripts...
I: Configuring e2fsprogs...
I: Configuring procps...
I: Configuring ifupdown...
I: Configuring upstart...
I: Configuring udev...
I: Configuring initramfs-tools...
I: Configuring plymouth...
I: Configuring libc-bin...
I: Configuring initramfs-tools...
I: Unpacking the base system...
I: Unpacking apt...
I: Unpacking binutils...
I: Unpacking build-essential...
I: Unpacking bzip2...
I: Unpacking cpp...
I: Unpacking cpp-4.8...
I: Unpacking dpkg-dev...
I: Unpacking g++...
I: Unpacking g++-4.8...
I: Unpacking gcc...
I: Unpacking gcc-4.8...
I: Unpacking gcc-4.8-base:amd64...
I: Unpacking gnupg...
I: Unpacking gpgv...
I: Unpacking libapt-pkg4.12:amd64...
I: Unpacking libasan0:amd64...
I: Unpacking libatomic1:amd64...
I: Unpacking libc-dev-bin...
I: Unpacking libc6-dev:amd64...
I: Unpacking libcloog-isl4:amd64...
I: Unpacking libdpkg-perl...
I: Unpacking libgcc-4.8-dev:amd64...
I: Unpacking libgdbm3:amd64...
I: Unpacking libgmp10:amd64...
I: Unpacking libgomp1:amd64...
I: Unpacking libisl10:amd64...
I: Unpacking libitm1:amd64...
I: Unpacking libmpc3:amd64...
I: Unpacking libmpfr4:amd64...
I: Unpacking libquadmath0:amd64...
I: Unpacking libreadline6:amd64...
I: Unpacking libstdc++-4.8-dev:amd64...
I: Unpacking libstdc++6:amd64...
I: Unpacking libtimedate-perl...
I: Unpacking libtsan0:amd64...
I: Unpacking libusb-0.1-4:amd64...
I: Unpacking linux-libc-dev:amd64...
I: Unpacking make...
I: Unpacking patch...
I: Unpacking perl...
I: Unpacking perl-modules...
I: Unpacking readline-common...
I: Unpacking ubuntu-keyring...
I: Unpacking xz-utils...
I: Configuring the base system...
I: Configuring gpgv...
I: Configuring libgdbm3:amd64...
I: Configuring libusb-0.1-4:amd64...
I: Configuring bzip2...
I: Configuring libc-dev-bin...
I: Configuring linux-libc-dev:amd64...
I: Configuring patch...
I: Configuring gcc-4.8-base:amd64...
I: Configuring libasan0:amd64...
I: Configuring xz-utils...
I: Configuring ubuntu-keyring...
I: Configuring make...
I: Configuring libgmp10:amd64...
I: Configuring libstdc++6:amd64...
I: Configuring libmpfr4:amd64...
I: Configuring binutils...
I: Configuring libgomp1:amd64...
I: Configuring readline-common...
I: Configuring libitm1:amd64...
I: Configuring libatomic1:amd64...
I: Configuring libc6-dev:amd64...
I: Configuring libquadmath0:amd64...
I: Configuring libtsan0:amd64...
I: Configuring libapt-pkg4.12:amd64...
I: Configuring libgcc-4.8-dev:amd64...
I: Configuring libisl10:amd64...
I: Configuring libreadline6:amd64...
I: Configuring libmpc3:amd64...
I: Configuring gnupg...
I: Configuring libstdc++-4.8-dev:amd64...
I: Configuring libcloog-isl4:amd64...
I: Configuring apt...
I: Configuring cpp-4.8...
I: Configuring gcc-4.8...
I: Configuring cpp...
I: Configuring gcc...
I: Configuring g++-4.8...
I: Configuring g++...
I: Configuring perl-modules...
I: Configuring perl...
I: Configuring libtimedate-perl...
I: Configuring libdpkg-perl...
I: Configuring dpkg-dev...
I: Configuring build-essential...
I: Configuring libc-bin...
I: Base system installed successfully.
I: debootstrap finished
I: copying local configuration
I: Installing apt-lines
I: Refreshing the base.tgz 
I: upgrading packages
I: mounting /proc filesystem
I: mounting /run/shm filesystem
I: mounting /dev/pts filesystem
I: installing dummy policy-rc.d
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en [762 kB]
Fetched 762 kB in 1s (677 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
I: Obtaining the cached apt archive contents
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/gnupg_1.4.16-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/locales_2.13+git20120306-12_all.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/g++_4%3a4.8.2-1ubuntu6_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/lsb-base_4.1+Debian11ubuntu6_all.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libselinux1_2.2.2-1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/initscripts_2.88dsf-41ubuntu6_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libgcc-4.8-dev_4.8.2-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libustr-1.0-1_1.0.4-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libsemanage1_2.2-1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libudev1_204-5ubuntu20_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/initramfs-tools_0.103ubuntu4_all.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libklibc_2.0.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libpam0g_1.1.8-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/liblzma5_5.1.1alpha+20120614-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libdb5.3_5.3.28-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libsemanage-common_2.2-1_all.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libitm1_4.8.2-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/make_3.81-8.2ubuntu3_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/base-files_7.2ubuntu5_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/adduser_3.113+nmu3ubuntu3_all.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/sysvinit-utils_2.88dsf-41ubuntu6_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/perl-modules_5.18.2-2ubuntu1_all.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/gcc_4%3a4.8.2-1ubuntu6_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/passwd_1%3a4.1.5.1-1ubuntu9_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/apt_1.0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/coreutils_8.21-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/grep_2.16-1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libquadmath0_4.8.2-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libpam-modules_1.1.8-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libcloog-isl4_0.18.2-1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libpam-runtime_1.1.8-1ubuntu2_all.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/ncurses-bin_5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libatomic1_4.8.2-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/debianutils_4.4_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/dpkg-dev_1.17.5ubuntu5_all.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/mawk_1.3.3-17ubuntu2_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libpcre3_1%3a8.31-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-libc-dev_3.13.0-24.46_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libasan0_4.8.2-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libcgmanager0_0.24-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libncurses5_5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/patch_2.7.1-4_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libapt-pkg4.12_1.0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libpng12-0_1.2.50-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libmount1_2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/xz-utils_5.1.1alpha+20120614-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/mount_2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/g++-4.8_4.8.2-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/makedev_2.3.1-93ubuntu1_all.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libprocps3_1%3a3.3.9-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/e2fslibs_1.42.9-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libgmp10_2%3a5.1.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/klibc-utils_2.0.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm2_2.4.52-1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/binutils_2.24-5ubuntu3_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libgcc1_1%3a4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libss2_1.42.9-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libmpfr4_3.1.2-1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/perl-base_5.18.2-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/sysv-rc_2.88dsf-41ubuntu6_all.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/perl_5.18.2-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/initramfs-tools-bin_0.103ubuntu4_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/findutils_4.4.2-7_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev_2.19-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libtimedate-perl_2.3000-1_all.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/gzip_1.6-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/bsdutils_1%3a2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libslang2_2.2.4-15ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libreadline6_6.3-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/udev_204-5ubuntu20_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/upstart_1.12.1-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/util-linux_2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libtinfo5_5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libaudit1_1%3a2.3.2-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libdebconfclient0_0.187ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libacl1_2.2.52-1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libpam-modules-bin_1.1.8-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libusb-0.1-4_2%3a0.1.12-23.3ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libc-dev-bin_2.19-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libdpkg-perl_1.17.5ubuntu5_all.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libuuid1_2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libkmod2_15-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-4.9-base_4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/procps_1%3a3.3.9-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/readline-common_6.3-4ubuntu2_all.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/base-passwd_3.5.33_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/e2fsprogs_1.42.9-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-4.8_4.8.2-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libgdbm3_1.8.3-12build1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libdbus-1-3_1.6.18-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/login_1%3a4.1.5.1-1ubuntu9_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/diffutils_1%3a3.3-1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libattr1_1%3a2.4.47-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/zlib1g_1%3a1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libaudit-common_1%3a2.3.2-2ubuntu1_all.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libblkid1_2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libisl10_0.12.2-1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libmpc3_1.0.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/busybox-initramfs_1%3a1.21.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/plymouth_0.8.8-0ubuntu17_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/bash_4.3-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/mountall_2.53_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libstdc++-4.8-dev_4.8.2-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/build-essential_11.6ubuntu6_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libjson-c2_0.11-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libcap2_1%3a2.24-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/ubuntu-keyring_2012.05.19_all.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/module-init-tools_15-0ubuntu6_all.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/iproute2_3.12.0-2_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libsepol1_2.2-1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/hostname_3.15ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/dash_0.5.7-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libncursesw5_5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/insserv_1.14.0-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-4.8-base_4.8.2-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libstdc++6_4.8.2-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libbz2-1.0_1.0.6-5_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libgomp1_4.8.2-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libtsan0_4.8.2-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/sensible-utils_0.0.9_all.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/tzdata_2014b-1_all.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/gpgv_1.4.16-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/bzip2_1.0.6-5_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libjson0_0.11-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/cpio_2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/kmod_15-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/cpp_4%3a4.8.2-1ubuntu6_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/multiarch-support_2.19-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libnih1_1.0.3-4ubuntu25_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libc-bin_2.19-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/sed_4.2.2-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libnih-dbus1_1.0.3-4ubuntu25_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libplymouth2_0.8.8-0ubuntu17_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/debconf_1.5.51ubuntu2_all.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.19-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/ncurses-base_5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1_all.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/ifupdown_0.7.47.2ubuntu4_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/libcomerr2_1.42.9-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/cpp-4.8_4.8.2-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link '/var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662/var/cache/apt/archives/tar_1.27.1-1_amd64.deb': File exists
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Package 'ccache' is not installed, so not removed
build-essential is already the newest version.
dpkg-dev is already the newest version.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  aptitude-common libboost-iostreams1.54.0 libcwidget3 libept1.4.12
  libsigc++-2.0-0c2a libsqlite3-0 libxapian22
Suggested packages:
  aptitude-doc-en aptitude-doc tasksel debtags libcwidget-dev xapian-tools
Recommended packages:
  apt-xapian-index libparse-debianchangelog-perl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  aptitude aptitude-common libboost-iostreams1.54.0 libcwidget3 libept1.4.12
  libsigc++-2.0-0c2a libsqlite3-0 libxapian22
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/3486 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package libsqlite3-0:amd64.
(Reading database ... 11701 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libsqlite3-0_3.8.2-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsqlite3-0:amd64 (3.8.2-1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-iostreams1.54.0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-iostreams1.54.0_1.54.0-4ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-iostreams1.54.0:amd64 (1.54.0-4ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libept1.4.12:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libept1.4.12_1.0.12_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libept1.4.12:amd64 (1.0.12) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsigc++-2.0-0c2a:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libsigc++-2.0-0c2a_2.2.10-0.2ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsigc++-2.0-0c2a:amd64 (2.2.10-0.2ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package aptitude-common.
Preparing to unpack .../aptitude-common_0.6.8.2-1ubuntu4_all.deb ...
Unpacking aptitude-common (0.6.8.2-1ubuntu4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcwidget3.
Preparing to unpack .../libcwidget3_0.5.16-3.5ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcwidget3 (0.5.16-3.5ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxapian22.
Preparing to unpack .../libxapian22_1.2.16-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxapian22 (1.2.16-2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package aptitude.
Preparing to unpack .../aptitude_0.6.8.2-1ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking aptitude (0.6.8.2-1ubuntu4) ...
Setting up libsqlite3-0:amd64 (3.8.2-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libboost-iostreams1.54.0:amd64 (1.54.0-4ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libept1.4.12:amd64 (1.0.12) ...
Setting up libsigc++-2.0-0c2a:amd64 (2.2.10-0.2ubuntu2) ...
Setting up aptitude-common (0.6.8.2-1ubuntu4) ...
Setting up libcwidget3 (0.5.16-3.5ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libxapian22 (1.2.16-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up aptitude (0.6.8.2-1ubuntu4) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/aptitude-curses to provide /usr/bin/aptitude (aptitude) in auto mode
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6) ...
I: Copying back the cached apt archive contents
I: unmounting dev/pts filesystem
I: unmounting run/shm filesystem
I: unmounting proc filesystem
I: creating base tarball [/var/cache/pbuilder/base.tgz]
I: cleaning the build env 
I: removing directory /var/cache/pbuilder/build//55662 and its subdirectories
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the `pbuilder --create` invocation is not to build Debian packages. Rather it is supposed to create a `base.tgz` (which is a compressed chroot). After creating such a `base.tgz` you can use it in conjunction with `pbuilder --build foo.dsc` to actually build a package.

Comment: When i run pbuilder --build myproject.dcs i get 
Can't exec "qmake": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debian/Debhelper/Dh_Lib.pm line 218.


Any idea what's the issue?

Comment: Missing `Build-Depends`?